# What's wrong with my pom.xml using liferay and maven (can't read dependencies.dependency.version)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When I try to maven build I get the following error into my project. I'm using eclipse, maven and liferay:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.liferay.portal:portal-service:jar must be a valid version but is '${liferay.version}'. @ line 98, column 13
[ERROR] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin must be a valid version but is '${liferay.maven.plugin.version}'. @ line 16, column 14
```

After building my project in eclipse with maven. Am I wrong writing the liferay version? Here is the POM, please help me!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>GSN_SVIL</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>GSN_SVIL Portlet</name>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liferay.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-css</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <autoDeployDir>${liferay.auto.deploy.dir}</autoDeployDir>
                    <appServerDeployDir>${liferay.app.server.deploy.dir}</appServerDeployDir>
                    <appServerLibGlobalDir>${liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir}</appServerLibGlobalDir>
                    <appServerPortalDir>${liferay.app.server.portal.dir}</appServerPortalDir>
                    <liferayVersion>${liferay.version}</liferayVersion>
                    <pluginType>portlet</pluginType>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>liferay-faces-bridge-impl</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4-ga5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>liferay-faces-portal</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4-ga5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>util-java</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>${liferay.version}</version> -->
<!--            <scope>provided</scope> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-el</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.GA</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.jboss.org</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.primefaces.org</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>Liferay-v6.2-CE-(Tomcat-7)</id>
            <properties>
                <liferay.version>6.2</liferay.version>
                <liferay.maven.plugin.version>1.0.0.47</liferay.maven.plugin.version>
                <liferay.auto.deploy.dir>E:\dev\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga4\deploy</liferay.auto.deploy.dir>
                <liferay.app.server.deploy.dir>E:\dev\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga4\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps</liferay.app.server.deploy.dir>
                <liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir>E:\dev\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga4\tomcat-7.0.42\lib\ext</liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir>
                <liferay.app.server.portal.dir>E:\dev\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga4\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\ROOT</liferay.app.server.portal.dir>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

How can I avoid the error above?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass version as the property you have to define them:

```
<properties>
    <liferay.version>your_liferay_version</liferay.version>
    <liferay.maven.plugin.version>your_maven_plugin_version</liferay.maven.plugin.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: I did it at the end of the code, but perhaps I'm wrong writing the version. Do you know what I have to write? i downloaded the 6.2-ce-ga4

Answer (score 1):

You configured the versions in a profile.

If you don't need profiles, dont use any, and configure the resources globally (for your pom) in

```
<project><properties><liferay.version>....</liferay.version>
```

if you want to use profiles, you can read :
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html